# Flush cache in particular template

Tags: magento2, custom-template

It is not working in .phtml template

```
                $types = array('full_page');
                foreach ($types as $type) {
                    $cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
                }
                foreach ($cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
                    $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
                }
```

Comment: Add the full code?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
try{
    $_cacheTypeList = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface');
    $_cacheFrontendPool = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool');
    $types = array('full_page');
    foreach ($types as $type) {
        $_cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
    }is
    foreach ($_cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
        $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $msg = 'Error : '.$e->getMessage();die();
}
```

Comment: tried this way, its not working only in templates

Comment: Its a working code. It's working for me.

Comment: it is working in blocks/controllers but not in .phtml file

Comment: Did you use object manager? which I have mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Used $objectmanager but it’s not working in template

Comment: I have pasted it in addtocart.phtml and its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
try{
    $_cacheTypeList = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface');
    $_cacheFrontendPool = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool');
    $types = array('full_page');

    foreach ($types as $type) {
        $_cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
    }

    foreach ($_cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {

        $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();

    }
}
catch(Exception $e){

    $e->getMessage();

}
```